# time data '07-01-20' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Tags: python

i have errorr like this

```
ValueError: time data '07-01-20' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

and this my code

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%d/%m/%Y')
akhir = pd.read_csv('akhir.csv', index_col=[0], date_parser=dateparse)
```

my data :
[image: data]

Comment: And dashes aren't slashes...

Comment: Please read your error messages

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a two-digit year, use `%y` instead of `%Y`; and if your data uses `-`s, you don't want your format string to use `/`s.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

---

Thus:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%d-%m-%y')
akhir = pd.read_csv('akhir.csv', index_col=[0], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Comment: ValueError: time data '07-01-20' does not match format '%d/%m/%y'

Comment: `-` is not `/`. Change your format string accordingly.